# Как переправить строку из одного файла в другой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

time выводит время в отдельный файл. Необходимо перехватить строку и переправить в конец другого файла. Не понимаю в чем загвоздка..

```
File.readlines('time.log', 'r') do |line|
    if line =~ /^real/
      File.new('table.log', 'a').puts(line)
    end
end
```

То что меня не устраивает, это обрезка строки:

```
real 15,775
```

Нужны только цифры. пробовал по разному регулярки прописывать.а они либо не работали, либо выводили что-то странное

```
File.new('table.log', 'a').puts(line[0])
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. Перенесите ваш "ответ" (который вас не полностью устраивает) в вопрос и приведите минимальный пример значений (файла, строк).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить число, тут есть несколько способов на выбор:

- С помощью простой регулярки `/\d+,\d+/` (1+ цифр, `,`, 1+ цифр)
- Разбить строку с помощью пробела и взять последний элемент
- Удалить `real` + пробелы в начале строки.

Пример кода:

```
s = 'real 15,775'
puts s[/\d+,\d+/]
puts s.split(" ").last
puts s.sub(/^real\s*/,'')
```

См. [демо на Ruby](http://ideone.com/u5E9jx).

Comment: Странно, вроде пробовал 1 вариант с цифрами `s =~ [/\d+, \d+/]`. Выводило ерунду что то вроде `7 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 с новой строки каждое числo`. Можно сослаться на неопытность. Благодарю.

Comment: К слову, так не работает применительно к элементу массова
`File.new('table.log', 'a').puts(line[0][/\d+,\d+/])`

Answer (score 0):

```
line = IO.readlines('time.log')
File.new('table.log', 'a').puts(line[0] =~ /[^\w]/)
```

Как-то так решил проблему. Однако не получается вытащить только цифры формата 1.784851 .